# Asynchronous Projections in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future, projection

Is it possible to do asynchronous projections in rust?

By a projection, I mean a method on a struct that returns a reference to one of its fields. A minimal *synchronous* example:

```rust
struct Aggregate<T>(T);

impl<T> Aggregate<T> {
    fn project(&self) -> &T {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

An *asynchronous projection* should not yield a `&T` but some `Future` with output `&T`. Naively trying to implement such a `Future` does not work; in the following example, the reference in the `Output` type `&T` (rightly so) requires a lifetime.

```rust
impl<T> Future for Aggregate<T> {
    type Output = &T;

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, _cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        Poll::Ready(self.project())
    }
}
```

A correct implementation would have to look like this:

```rust
impl<T> Future for Aggregate<T> {
    type Output<'s> = &'s T where T: 's;

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, _cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output<'_>> {
        Poll::Ready(self.project())
    }
}
```

But this clashes with the definition of the `Future` trait, which does not accept a lifetime for `Output`:

```
lifetime parameters or bounds on type `Output` do not match the trait declaration
lifetimes do not match type in trait rustcE0195
```

Is there any way of getting this to work with the core `Future` trait, or would a dedicated `LendingFuture` trait be needed (analogous to how a [LendingIterator](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/08/03/GATs-stabilization-push.html#so-what-are-gats) needs a new, dedicated trait)?

If this is not possible to do with the `Future` trait, are there workarounds and/or are there plans to provide a `LendingFuture` in `core` eventually?

---

I want to explicitly implement `Future` for some first-class type, not rely on some type automatically generated by `async fn` desugaring or on trait objects.

My interest in asynchronous projections comes from exploring asynchronous APIs in the style of [bytes::Buf](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.2.1/bytes/trait.Buf.html#), the [chunk](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.2.1/bytes/trait.Buf.html#tymethod.chunk) method boils down to a projection. For *way more* details, see [panda_pile::why](https://docs.rs/panda_pile/0.2.0/panda_pile/why/index.html), and [this section](https://docs.rs/panda_pile/0.2.0/panda_pile/#nonblocking-traits) for why I'm interested in explicitly working with futures rather than with async functions.

Comment: Simply tacking `async` to your `project` function works: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=71289f3120c7b31cb0361578d9071f6f).

Comment: Both your `project()` function and the future of its `async` version are like implementing `Future` on `&Aggregate`, not on `Aggregate`.